# Ajax call back function to redirect another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to capture 901 error codes in my header.jsp to handle ajax errors globally.

In browser console I am getting:

> GET https://localhost:8443/SSApp/Pan/report?&vessel…namax%20Tanker%20Pool%20Limited&rptTitle=Activity%20Report&_=1431351700771 901 (OK)

How can I capture and redirect on the basis of whether we got 901 error code or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ajax status code:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    400: function() {
      alert('400 status code! user error');
    },
    901: function() {
      alert('error 901');
    }
  }
});
```